# Server Side Rendering for improving SEO of landing page in already existing React + jQuery Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, server-side-rendering

I have an already existing website that has a pretty huge codebase. It was initially built in jQuery and is currently being migrated to ReactJS so both are used in conjunction as of now.

**The problem is**: I am migrating the landing page from jQuery to ReactJS. For obvious reasons, I need this particular page to be able to be crawled by search engines and to have SEO. Is it possible to have just this one page to be rendered server-side?

**What I've already *looked* into**:

1. I have already looked into other frameworks like NextJS, Razzle, etc but realized later that it does not apply to my use case since I do not want another separate project in the codebase with duplicate components.  I just want the landing page to be rendered on the server side.
2. I have looked into the in-house SSR utility provided by ReactJS.
3. I have looked into the partial server-side rendering solution provided here: [SSR-with-ReactJS](https://dev.to/juhanakristian/basics-of-react-server-side-rendering-with-expressjs-phd)

So far solution #3 looks the most promising and easily applicable to my situation.

I've scoured the internet in the past couple of days and couldn't find anything else apart from these. Are there any better ways to handle this situation aside from the one's mentioned?

Thanks